# On freenode using Weechat, why does my nick sometimes end with a digit like 1, 2, or 3?

Tags: sleep, irc, weechat, freenode

Usually I have this issue if my computer goes to sleep with irc on (Weechat client). When I wake my computer up, I end up reconnecting to the server but as `[nick]2`, `[nick]3`, etc.

Additionally, how do you prevent yourself from continuously disconnecting and reconnecting throughout the day as your computer goes in and out of sleep? I'm new to irc and this seems like it could be an annoying issue for others in the channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your computer goes to sleep the network connection is lost.  It may take a few minutes for the IRC server to recognize you have disconnected and release your nick. If you reconnect before this happens your client will get a "nick already in use" error. Your client likely handles this by automatically appending a number to your nick and trying again.

There is no way to maintain your connection while your computer goes to sleep.  There are some clients that can be setup as a sort of relay where you connect to the IRC on a VPS or other machine that never sleeps then have your desktop connect to it instead.

Comment: Thanks @kicken, I've edited my question to clarify that I'm using Weechat. To follow-up, is there a way I could avoid this issue (e.g. by changing a config file)? Of the hundreds of other names I see in the channel, I seem to be the only one, but perhaps this is ultimately a non-issue.

Comment: I am not familiar with weechat, maybe someone else can provide specific advice.  What I said applies pretty generally to IRC regardless of client.